# Issues in performing operations with KIbana dashboard : 501 Not Implemented

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana-5

I have Kibana and Elasticsearch installed on AWS instance. Elasticsearch seems to work fine. However when I try to perform some action (PUT and DELETE requests) using Kibana dashboard it gives me error  `501 (Not Implemented)`. It works in case of GET requests .I access Kibana from my local system using `http://aws-ip:5601/`. Below is the error trace that I get

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 501 (Not Implemented)
commons.bundle.js?v=15104:38 Error: Not Implemented
at respond (kibana.bundle.js?v=15104:13)
at checkRespForFailure (kibana.bundle.js?v=15104:13)
at kibana.bundle.js?v=15104:1
at processQueue (commons.bundle.js?v=15104:38)
at commons.bundle.js?v=15104:38
at Scope.$eval (commons.bundle.js?v=15104:39)
at Scope.$digest (commons.bundle.js?v=15104:39)
at Scope.$apply (commons.bundle.js?v=15104:39)
at done (commons.bundle.js?v=15104:37)
at completeRequest (commons.bundle.js?v=15104:37)
(anonymous) @ commons.bundle.js?v=15104:38
```

Also if I copy the request payload from network tab of Chrome developer tools and perform the same request (PUT/DELETE) using CURL from AWS terminal, it works fine.

Please help!!!

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting my findings in case somebody else is also stuck in similar type of situation. In my case , corporate proxy was just blocking PUT and DELETE requests resulting in 501 (Not implemented) error.